# mb_split parsing function not working with Japanese characters UTF-8 text?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse utf-8 encoded text files uploaded via a `multipart/form-data` form.  I have built a small `.txt` file where I have entered some tab delimited (meaningless) text in both latin and Japanese characters (I copy/pasted the Jpz characters from a Jpz retail site).

All I am trying at this point is to replace new lines by `(LINE)` and tabs by `(TAB)`.  Here is my code:

```
...
$text=file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);

$LineArray=array('\r\n','\n\r','\r','\n');
foreach ($LineArray as $value){
  $pieces=(mb_split($value,$text));
  $text=implode ("(LINE)",$pieces);
}
echo "Here is the modified text:<br/>";
echo $text;
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($text);

$tab='\t';
$pieces=(mb_split($tab,$text));
$text=implode ("(TAB)",$pieces);
echo "Here is the modified text:<br/>";
echo $text;
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($text);
...
```

Here is a vardump of the text before modification:

```
string 'John    Fitzgerald  Kennedy

Winston     Churchill

John    Edgar   Hoover

素材の 生地を柿渋で染 めた和柄パンツです





火车票 火车票 火车票 火车票



' (length=175)
```

The first line of Asian characters has 2 tabs, the last line of the file has 3 tabs.

Here is a vardump of the text after all modifications:

```
string 'John(TAB)Fitzgerald(TAB)Kennedy(LINE)Winston(TAB)(TAB)Churchill(LINE)John(TAB)Edgar(TAB)Hoover(LINE)素材の 生地を柿渋で染(TAB)めた和柄パンツです(LINE)(LINE)(LINE)火车票  火车票 火车票 火车票(LINE)(LINE)' (length=235)
```

How come my code can only identify one of the tabs in the Japanese text part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mb_split` uses the value of [`mb_regex_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php) to determine what encoding to process the string in. This value is probably not set to `UTF-8` and hence `mb_split` doesn't expect/work on the correct encoding. Try setting the `mb_regex_encoding` to UTF-8.

Comment: Ding, ding, ding...  That works.  Thank you.  I thought all I had to do to ensure I was UTF-8 throughout had been done.  I need to get more info on `mb_internal_encoding` and `mb_regex_encoding`.